# Post controller value is always null while sending through postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have MVC architecture project.now i want to give api to android developer .so how can i test the POST API services through POSTMAN.when i send post service through postman it will return null value..

url:-http://localhost/Master/AddEmployee

```
JSON DATA:-
{
    "EmpFName":"Sa",
    "EmpMName":"s",
    "EmpLName":"SS",
     "AadhaarCardNumber":null,
     "PanCardNumber":null,
     "DateOfBirth":"1993-10-20T00:00:00",
     "Address":"Pune",
     "City":"Pune",
     "State":"Maharashtra",
     "Country":"India",
     "PinCode":"410505",
     "EmailID":"sa@GMAIL.COM",
     "Password":"123456",
     "PhotoPath":null,
     "MobileNo":"74487855545",
     "EmergancyContactNo":"7447774558",
     "MaritalStatus":"single",
     "Designation":"devlop",
     "ReportingMgr":1,
     "LeaveCount":18,
     "SpouseName":null,
     "SpDOB":null,
     "SpAge":null,
     "FirstChildName":null,
     "FCDOB":null,
     "FCAge":null,
     "SecondChidName":null,
     "SCDOB":null,
     "SCAge":null,
     "IsActive":true,
     "CreatedBy":null,
     "UpdatedOn":null,
     "Gender":"Female",
     "SCGender":"Male",
     "SpGender":"Female",
     "FCGender":"female"
}
```

cODE:-

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("addemmployee")]
public ActionResult AddEmployee( FormCollection form)
{
    //employeedata empdata;

    try
    {
        Employee emp = new Employee();

        emp.JoiningDate = Convert.ToDateTime(form["joining_date"]);
        emp.EmpFName = form["txt_fname"];
        emp.EmpMName = form["txt_mname"];
        emp.EmpLName = form["txt_lname"];
        emp.AadhaarCardNumber = form["aadhaarnum"];

        MasterReposities.SaveEmployee(emp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you write a custom binder, I don't believe JSON will serialize to a FormCollection by default.

Try passing an actual Form:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

or

```
multipart/form-data
```

Or to handle JSON, make sure you have your project configured with JSON Model binders (Web API should be setup by default) and change the model parameter to  your method to the actual domain object, then the JSON model binder will just do the work for you, assuming your C# model properties match the JSON property names:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("addemmployee")]
public ActionResult AddEmployee(Employee emp)
{
}
```

If you convert this to a Web API project, make sure to inherit from *ApiController*